# Susy at-breakpoint not breaking at intended points

Tags: css, linux, sass, susy-compass

I am learning Susy and I am trying to use at-breakpoint and running into some weirdness.

I posted a gist and it's also on sassmeister:

http://sassmeister.com/gist/7050948

https://gist.github.com/keithhayden/7050948

I defined some variables for my media layouts:

```
$susy-phone-wide:       24em 8       // 384px
$susy-tablet-portrait:  30em 12      // 480px to 600px
$susy-tablet-landscape: 37.5em 16    // 600px to 768px
$susy-computer:         48em 24      // 768px to ?
```

Then just to see where the breakpoints are taking effect, I just have a div that changes color at each breakpoint.
The problem is, it's changing color at the wrong breakpoints.

- should turn green at 384px, doesn't change until 480px  ( -96px )
- should turn yellow at 480px, doesn't change until 600px ( -120px )
- should turn red at 600px, doesn't change until 750px    ( -150px )
- should turn purple at 768px, doesn't change until 960px ( -192px )

perhaps my math is off on the em values for the media-layouts. I used pxtoem.com to calculate the em values.

The actual practical use case is I'll be adding buttons that on mobile devices will be arranged top to bottom and width 100%, but once on a non-mobile device, they become width auto and are arranged right to left.

Comment: I tried it in your sassmeister gist in Chrome 30 on OS X and the breaking points work exactly as expected. The only thing that is putting it off a bit (a couple of px) is the vertical scroller if the output window is not high enough.

Comment: ok, then maybe it's just me. I'm on an Ubuntu laptop with Chrome 30. I noticed that fonts look bigger on Ubuntu than they do on a Mac or Windows machine, so perhaps that's what's throwing it off.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2):

I checked it out on Ubuntu in Chrome 26 and it also seemed totally fine. But then I played around with the preferences a little in `chrome://settings`, where (if you show advanced settings) under

#### Web Content

I had set this:

- Font size: *medium*
- Page Zoom: *100%*

If I changed the font to *Large* the page started behaving the way you experience it.

So this will happen no matter what if using relative units in media queries. If the browser overrides the base for the unit. You can change just the media queries to `px` and use relative units on the rest of the design ... I am not sure how this will affect your grid solution ... but it would get rid of this behavior.

However, when changing the font to large in the browser or zooming-in the viewport starts emulating a smaller device ... so basically, the behavior you get originally is correct (you just shouldn't look at the actual pixels anymore). And if I would zoom-in (or set the `em` base huge) enough I would get the buttons arranged top-to-bottom ... because my screen width to font (`em`-base) ratio would be similar to one on a handheld device.

Comment: Yes, em-based media-queries are always calculated against the browser default setting — ignoring even your root font-size settings. This is silly, but it's the way CSS works. If the browser default is larger or smaller than your expected em-size, there will be a mis-match between your calculations and the actual results. If you're using em-based media-queries, you get em-based results — and those can never be reliably compared to pixels. That's the advantage and difficulty: they're relative instead of fixed, for better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Since I've had several people tell me all is right for them, I assume the issue is on my end. I have noticed that on my Ubuntu machine the fonts on some sites seem to be a little taller and wider and sometimes wrap when they don't on other systems. browser is not zoomed in, so I need to ask a question in an ubuntu forum I guess.